# JAVA manipulate docx DOCVARIABLE in text boxes

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am developing an JAVA server-side application that would fill in some texts on a Microsoft Word Docx file. The Docx file contains multiple textboxes, each has a DOCVARIABLE filled in and the text style adjusted to make the form look great.

I have already tried Apache POI, which does locate the textboxes but can't modify the DOCVARIABLES. Even if I am to replace the DOCVARIABLES with placeholder texts POI won't let me modify text in textboxes. Since this is a server-side application, I couldn't adopt C# solutions that would need a complete msword.exe to run.

Could anyone shed some light on how I should proceed? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to this problem after research for a while.

[Docx4j](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) is the package to use in this scenario. It provided a function to traverse the document and grasp texts in any containers. The docx file then needs to be modified, instead of having DOCVARIABLES, use MERGEFIELD, or plain text and do your own trick.